# Why do people dislike being deceived?

Tags: ethics, belief

First and foremost, this question seems like it has simple answer, but I wasn't able to find a satisfying one when thinking about it further.

To expand on it:

### Why is the notion of being deceived so unacceptable to an individual, oftentimes more unacceptable than the possibility of injury, death, isolation or worse?

The instances of this appear over and again both in literature, movies, as well as everyday lives:

- Movies like The Truman show, Matrix trilogy, and a plethora of other pieces explore this issue, setting the deception as the center-point and main antagonist of its plot. In these specific cases, while there is a tangible main antagonist (e.g. Agent Smith in Matrix or Christof in the Truman show), it is the act of deceiving, which is (at least I feel so) their worst wrong-doing, while the actual harm (taking advantage of the deceived) is not as unsettling.
- Conspiracy theories and cults more often than not use the fear of being deceived as the most efficient tool to recruit new member (and keep existing members inside). I would even go as far as to say that this fear of being lied to is the one and sole reason why such groups cannot be deconstructed using logic and reason.

---

When searching for answers to this question, the "obvious" answers come to mind:

- Being lied to shows **weakness** of the individual. It makes them appear gullible, which hurts their ego, and/or shows their inferiority.
- Lies are used to take advantage of someone, thus making them do things that **aren't beneficial** for themselves, while also doing so not of their free will.
- Lies are **morally wrong**, and therefore people dislike them as they oppose their moral compass.

---

However, I find these answers lacking. For example:

- **What if the one being deceived is benefiting from it?** Again turning back to the previous examples, people living in the matrix live realistically much more fulfilled life than they could ever achieved in the dystopian real world. Yet the protagonists as well as anyone watching, feel the need to "make things right", even under the threat of injury, death or worse.
- **What if the lie is out of reach, as is most often the case in real world?** E.g. governments. During and after elections there are many demonstrations and protests of handfuls of people criticizing the government and demanding resignation, etc. These demonstrations however scarcely achieve any change.
- **What if fighting the lie results in more harm than accepting it?** Although whistleblowers aren't the best example here as their motivation is often the well-being of other rather than simply showing the truth, but there are certainly cases when removing a harmful lie sets things in motion which result in even greater harm.

---

This all is not to say I do not share these feelings. I too despise the feeling of being deceived and would much rather know the hurtful/harmful truth than living in a lie. However, I can't see the root of this feeling.

Comment: Social constraints: in order to live together truthfulness is more useful.

Comment: Oh go on. People *LOVE* to be deceived. "Do these jeans make me look fat?"  "Will I win the lottery?" "Do you love me?" "Is this really sugar free?"

Comment: The ethics of using deception in psychology is a current hot topic. You may consider posting this topic on the psychology SE.

Comment: There's this character in a film, I forgot his name, but he's blond and has a cleft chin, and now that I recall, he never lies, not once even, in the entire movie. It was in all likelihood totally unplanned. 

Comment: idk you can belittle truthfulness as mere social cohesion @MauroALLEGRANZA but you need a minimum amount for coherence

Answer (score 3):

This is more a question of sociology or anthropology than of philosophy. The simple answer is that human beings depend on other human beings for just about everything. I mean, look around your place: unless you are a truly unique individual there is almost nothing there that you made for yourself, by yourself. Most likely you produced something and earned 'trade rights' (e.g., money, credit, favor, etc), and used those 'trade rights' to procure things you wanted and needed. A man alone on a desert isle doesn't even rise to the level of hunter gatherer — which are distinct social exchange roles — but is forced down to something close to animal existence.

With that fact in mind, lying become a deep existential threat. We *have* to trust that 'trade rights' will be honored and respected; we *have* to trust that others will deal fairly with us; we *have* to trust that there is a common understanding of the world that lies between us and others. If we cannot trust those things, our ability to get what we want and need is put in jeopardy. People dislike being deceived because even small deceits bring our trust of the world into question. Anxiety, anger, and resentment are natural responses to existential threats, and no one likes those emotions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are that many good answers as to "why we feel something", often times we just do and conjecture a reason for that afterwards. And even if there are answers they are most likely rather in the realm of psychology.

That being said, being lied to actually is a serious matter. Like whether real or illusionary we perceive ourselves to have "free will", in the sense that we posses agency to live our lives how we want it. We are constraint by nature, but we can learn how it works and either adapt to that or shape our environment to our needs. This agency is most often a defining part of ourselves, who we are and what we see as our purpose in life.

Now if you're lied to, you're essentially fed inauthentic input. So if you learn from that experience and rationalize your actions based on that and build your worldview and your conception of what the world and you yourself are about, based on that then it's also inauthentic. You're living in a fantasy world of the liars creation, you're not living "your life" but you're deprived of that agency and relegated to being a tool in another person's simulation of life.

Like usually we could learn from trial and error, however when living in a lie you can't even do that. You can't learn the rules of the world because they are inconsistent, because the liar, as an imperfect god of that world, probably can't make them be consistent. And if you're unable to learn, plan and conceptualize, you're loosing your "self". Like if your perception is meaningless and/or you can't trust it you'd literally go insane. Life would be gambling with unstable odds, so what would be the point of even having a planing agency in your brain or the other way around if you would still try to make sense of it all you might come up with so many exceptions to any and all rules that you appear like the crazy conspiracy people with their incomprehensible mind maps.

> What if the one being deceived is benefiting from it?

You're deprived of the agency to define for yourself what is beneficial or the agency to decide for yourself what you'd find more beneficial. Like at times I find the solution to a problem more interesting than the absence of a problem. Like problems are not just hindrances but also challenges and completely without them you're not allowed to grow.

> What if the lie is out of reach, as is most often the case in real world?

I mean conspiracy theories usually focus on the wrong part of the story. That is if a handful of people can decide something without the knowledge of the general public, without accountability and without transparency then THAT is the problem, whatever they do with that power is just a symptom.

> What if fighting the lie results in more harm than accepting it?

Again you're taking away the agency of other people to decide that for themselves.

TL;DR lying to people is taking away peoples agency and the first step to problem solving is the ability to solve a problem (analyzing real data, pattern finding, transfer of learned patterns to new problems) so if you're deprived of that ability, regaining that ability is usually paramount over literally anything else.

Also people who act upon false data, rationalize their way to conclusions that are not rational to other people (garbage in garbage out), so the ability of society to understand their behavior is also lost and they appear erratic. Likewise if the individual has a feeling of immense powerlessness and helplessness their counter reactions to that might end up being extreme in order to compensate for the unequal distribution of power so stuff like that can be really dangerous as well. Which is why even society might have an incentive to frown upon lying and deception.

Answer (score 0):

The discovery of deception is impactful because it is evidence that ones personal view of the world was wrong. In a sense, it challenges one's confidence in their view of reality since there may be other examples of deception that have not yet been discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Agency, control and safety.

When people are deceived, they are being robbed of agency; the ability to - as much as possible - make decisions and act appropriately in response to the information they receive.

To be deceived is to risk acting in ways other than you otherwise might, for reasons which might not actually exist, incurring results which might be undesirable; undesirable in particular relation to the goal of being *safe*.

Without a sense of agency, we feel as though we are out of control, and one of our greatest needs is to control environment. Control makes us feel safe and provides us with the idea that we *might be able to reliably act in ways which make us safe*.

Many psychologists and psychiatrists agree that most of our behaviour - whether it be a search for affection, criminality, orderliness, ambition, even psychological disorder - is at root an expression of our desire for safety. Safety is, according to many, our primary urge. It infuses almost everything we do. This makes sense from an evolutionary perspective, in which we need to survive long enough to pass our genes on to successive generations, and to protect those successive generations as they try to navigate the world as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because *knowledge implies ability to predict*.

For example, knowing a path implies the ability to foresee what will be the direction in any point. Knowing your home implies you can predict the number of rooms, without actually exploring the home once more.

*When knowledge is wrong, the subject is vulnerable, since prediction might go wrong, up to the point of risking death*.

Driving on an unknown road implies the risk of having an accident. Expecting a fact that doesn't occur implies a risk, perhaps of death.

Such is the fact that the movies you mention explore. If you come to know your life has been a reality show, you will feel vulnerable: you are being exploited, as an individual, commercially, you cannot trust your wife, since he was lying, you become alone, isolated, vulnerable. At minimum, you can forget well-being. But chances are your probabilities of survival actually decrease. In the worst case you can die (e.g. Truman leaves his homeworld -where traffic is controlled-, and gets hit by a car).